# Change UITableView section header/footer WHILE RUNNING the app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header, title, footer

I'm facing a problem I cannot resolve...
I have a grouped table whose section header and section footer get displayed correctly upon launch thanks to

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Yet, I can't figure out how to update them later, I don't know how to change those texts and it's quite frustrating because in my mind it had to be nothing harder than changing a text label or whatever... (some ".text" property...)

I searched all through the documentation with no luck...

Any help is highly & kindly appreciated!
Regards,
Enrico

Comment: Is there a way to update the headers/footers WITHOUT reloading the full table... or the full section?   Update *JUST* the headers/footers.

Comment: I don't believe updating just a portion of the tableview will gain you anythings or that you'll see a difference in performance.

Answer (score 25):

In the delegate method, add a method call that returns the section name, e.g.:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case firstSectionTag:
            return [self firstSectionTitle];
        case secondSectionTag:
            return [self secondSectionTitle];
        // ...
        default:
            return nil;
    }
}

- (NSString *)firstSectionTitle {
    // generate first section title programmatically, e.g. "return [[NSDate date] description];" 
}

// ...
```

Then, when you need to update the section title, send an `NSNotification` that triggers something like the following method:

```
- (void)refreshTableSectionTitles:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

If the table is large and you want finer control, pass an `NSNotification` with an `NSDictionary` that contains the section you want to reload, read the dictionary in `-refreshTableSectionTitles` to get back the section `NSInteger`, and use the table view's [`-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW36) to reload that specific section.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
-(void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

And in

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

define your new header text in statement.

This will make a nice animation while changing the header/footer.

Answer (score 4):

Use this line in your code where you want to change the title:

```
    [[self theTableViewToChangeItsHeader]reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: on iOS 7 this causes the cells in the section to dissapear.

Comment: This question was related to ios 5.1. Did you seriously downvote it? :D

Answer (score -4):

In Your TableViewController use

```
[self.tableView reloadSectionIndexTitles];
```

Comment: doesn't reload footer text

Comment: This only applies to the index bar shown along the right side of the screen while scrolling.