# How do I access UITableView section label from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: xcode, tableview, sections

In my tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath I can access the cell textLabel. How do I access the section label?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    topPlacesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (topPlacesAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  
    appDelegate.chosenPhoto = [self.topPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
. . . 
    UITableViewCell *mycell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"   indexPath.section / Row = %i / %i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"   textLabel.text          = %@", mycell.textLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"   detailTextLabel.text    = %@", mycell.detailTextLabel.text);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show Site Table" sender:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the table section header.  I don't think you can read or otherwise access that data.  But you can *set* it with the method on the UITableViewDataSource:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Details are described here:

[Change UITableView section header/footer WHILE RUNNING the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547497/change-uitableview-section-header-footer-while-running-the-app)